# Building a bluetooth buzzer

Tags: bluetooth, programming, bluetooth-low-energy

I'm hoping to build a simple bluetooth buzzer using a [Serial Port BLE module: HM-10](http://imall.iteadstudio.com/im130614001.html). When a slave connected to it, if the slave sends a certain predefined message, the buzzer sounds for one minute.

The HM-10 has PIO pins, so I'm guessing I could use one to power the buzzer. To control the buzzer (or the pins, in general), read the message, etc., would I need to reprogram the HM-10 entirely? That is, the AT interface should be no good and the HM-10 will need to be flashed - is that right? If so, what is the canonical approach to programming it? How about the CC Debugger?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Communication devices that have a built-in GPIO bank typically include the ability to control those pins through whichever protocol they use to interface with the outside world. According to the [datasheet for the HM-10](http://www.pridopia.co.uk/pi-doc/BT4.0-HM-10-Serial_Port_BLE_Module_Master_Slave.pdf) you just use standard AT commands.

On pages 9 and 10:

> 6. Query/Set PIO pins output high or low (...)
>
>    - `AT+PIO [pin number] ?` to query;
>    - `AT+PIO [pin number] [0 or 1]` to set low or high.

Comment: Indeed. However, I'd like to read the message/command the slave sends to determine if the buzzer should sound. I don't think the AT interface supports that - am i right?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Apolgies for misunderstanding your original question. You'll need an MCU connected to the master to decipher the UART messages and then turn on the buzzer. If you wanted the master device to turn on the buzzer, you'd have to get the slave to send the AT command.

Comment: Thanks. Could the HM10 not be (re) programmed/flashed though?

Comment: Yes - see the manufacturer's website. No - you'd have to have a custom firmware.

Comment: Can these AT commands be given remotely, via Bluetooth? For HC05 it appears you can't, is this different for HM10?